# Can't combine haven-labelled & double

Tags: r, variables, group, mutate

I'm currently learning R and just tried to group a dataset into age groups. However, I received the following error message:

```
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: age_group = case_when(...).
Caused by error in case_when():
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in vec_compare():
! Can't combine ..1 <haven_labelled> and ..2 <double>.
```

My command was:

```
ess10_de <- mutate(ess10_de, age_group = case_when(agea>=15 & agea <30 ~1, 
                                                   agea>=30 & agea<50 ~2,
                                                   agea>=50 & agea<70 ~3, 
                                                   agea>=70 & agea<91 ~4, 
                                                   is.na(agea) ~ NA_real_))
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the platform! The error message is actually quite clear here: When you ask R to create age groups, it will need to make comparisons, e.g., `agea >= 15`. Even though `agea` might look like numbers (and thus should be comparable to `15`), apparently it comes with Stata labels attached and is therefore considered to be of type `haven_labelled`.

I don't have access to your data but you can try the two functions below to get rid of all Stata labels and end up with "clean" data.

```r
library(haven)

ess10_de |> 
  zap_label() |> 
  zap_labels()
```

Another tip (although unrelated to the error message): You don't have to use Stata's cumbersome way of defining age groups – instead you can use `cut()`:

```r
cut(x,
    breaks = c(15, 30, 50, 70, 91),
    labels = 1:4)
```

...where `x` is the column from your data and `labels` are optional in R.

Comment: thank you very much! tomorrow I will try to get it right :D